# Rhsiny: Automatically update an output object based on updated rhandsontable object

Tags: shiny, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity, rhandsontable, shinyapps

I have an app with two tables. One table is a renderhandsontable object and the other is just a rendertable object. I would like for when I update my renderhandsontable object for it to automatically update my rendertable object. My renderhandontable object is created by data elsewhere in the app using a number of filters.

I have referenced several very useful posts here to help me get this far in creating a reactive table that could be used in multiple output objects such as

[How to render multiple output from the same analysis without executing it multiple time? (Shiny)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37075830/how-to-render-multiple-output-from-the-same-analysis-without-executing-it-multip)

[Get selected rows of Rhandsontable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30733573/get-selected-rows-of-rhandsontable)

[Handsontable : how to change cell value in render function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037422/handsontable-how-to-change-cell-value-in-render-function)

but I cannot seem to get past this last hurdle. I also tried adding a button (using *eventReactive*) so the table would update when I pressed it rather than automatically, but had no luck there (and automatic would definitely be preferred).

I have created an overly simplified version of my *server* code below.

```
#dummy data
x = c('A','A','A', 'B','B', 'c')
y = c('G1', 'G1', 'G1', 'G2', 'G2','G3')
z = c('100', '200', '300', '400','500','600')

b=data.frame('Category' = x,
             'Group' = y,
             'Total' = z)

#create reactive object to be used in multiple places
test <- reactive({

  t <-filter(b, b$Category %in% input$cat & b$Group %in% input$group)

  return(t)

})

output$test_table <- renderTable({

  tbl = data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 4, nrow = 4))

#I know something needs to be done prior to this step to get updated values #of test()

  tbl[1,1] <- test()[1,3]

  return(tbl)
})


output$contents <- renderRHandsontable({

  rhandsontable(test())

})
```

I can get my tables to appear properly and the data to update initially, but once I make an update to my table, it is not reflected in my second table.

I have really been struggling with this for quite some time so any help or hints would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read [this](https://jrowen.github.io/rhandsontable/#shiny). You can access the rhandsontable [params](https://github.com/jrowen/rhandsontable/blob/master/inst/htmlwidgets/rhandsontable.js) via `input$my_id`. To get the current data use input$my_id$params$data.

Here is what I think you are after:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- fluidPage(rHandsontableOutput("contents"),
                tableOutput("test_table"),
                tableOutput("test_table_subset"))

server <- function(input, output) {

  # dummy data
  x = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C')
  y = c('G1', 'G1', 'G1', 'G2', 'G2', 'G3')
  z = c('100', '200', '300', '400', '500', '600')

  b = data.frame('Category' = x,
                 'Group' = y,
                 'Total' = z)

  # create reactive object to be used in multiple places
  test <- reactive({
    t <- b # dplyr::filter(b, b$Category %in% input$cat & b$Group %in% input$group)
    return(t)
  })

  output$contents <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(test())
  })

  contentsTableDat <- reactive({
    req(input$contents)
    hot_to_r(input$contents)
  })

  output$test_table <- renderTable({
    contentsTableDat()
  })

  output$test_table_subset <- renderTable({
    contentsTableDat()[1, 3]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you @ismirsehregal ! I knew I had to use "$" but I could not totally follow all of the examples and could not find solid documentation somewhere. I am currently getting an error: "Warning: Error in <-: invalid subscript type 'list'". I will continue to play around with it and see if this helps though !

Comment: @CjV That is because you didn't provide `input$cat` and `input$group` for your `filter` call. Please see my edit.

Comment: That makes sense thank you @ismirsehregal ! One more question, how would I access just an element of the reactive table ? For example, if I wanted to just use the value in the 1st row, 3rd column to update the table (my data will change from this simplified format-it will likely end up using a whole column and multiplying data in the other table by that column), it does not appear that I can do input$contents$params$data[1,3] ? Does my question make sense? Is there a way to treat is as a data frame?

Comment: You are receiving a `list()` you can access it like: `input$contents$params$data[[1]][3]` or take the data.frame I prepared:  `contentsTableDat[1, 3]`

Comment: This has been really helpful ! Thank you so much for the explanations !

Comment: Revisiting this: This code worked perfectly for me ! The new issue I am having now (my data is no longer that format) is using "gather" with the reactive output. When I do `data <-  gather(contentsTableDat(),key = Date,value = col4,-c(col1,col2,col3))` I get the error `Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'gather_' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'list')"`. I have tried a number of different ways on indexing the table to treat it as a data frame but have had no luck. I am having difficulty changing the column names as well.Do you know why I may be getting this error?

Comment: Just updated my answer using `hot_to_r` you might want to try it. But actually I think it might be better if you post another question illustrating the new problem.